# How can I prevent CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() from executing automatically on key press?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, routed-commands

`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` is called automatically every time a key has been pressed, when the focus has changed etc. I'd like to prevent this from happening under certain conditions (for example only call it when keys pressed are not `Up` or `Down`) and do my own handling of `RoutedCommands`, because `InvalidateRequerySuggested()` always processes all commands and is a bit slow.

I can see [in the reference source where `InvalidateRequerySuggested` is called](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Command/CommandDevice.cs#140), but I don't see a way to intervene there. There is a `PreProcessInput` event, but the necessary information you'd need from it is hidden in internal classes like `InputReportEventArgs`.

Is there a way?

Comment: In general, to determine whether an `ICommand` is enabled or not, we handle the `CanExecute` method. Also, you should be careful about changing the default way that certain functionality works... you could really annoy your users that will be expecting normal behaviour.

Comment: @Sheridan I want to continue using `CanExecute`. And there is no change in UI behaviour either (other than it being faster). I just want to do something manually that is done automatically otherwise.

Comment: Ok, well good luck with that.